# Prestashop order-confirmation email attachement (terms and conditions)

Tags: email, attachment, prestashop, confirmation-email

I am using Prestashop 1.5.4.1 and i need to add new file attachment (.docx document), which is stored on my server, to an order confirmation email. What should i do?

Thanks for Your time
sincerely 
Johan

Comment: I would recommend adding a link to your document in your email template instead of sending it as an attachment. Also using `docx` format is not very appropriate, I would use PDF.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did like a plan B. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 Mail::Send(
    5,
   'new_order',
   'New Order',
   array('{provider}' => 'Provider', '{title}' => 'My ePortal'),
   'provider@myportal.com',
   array('content' => $content, 'name' => $file, 'mime' => 'application/xml'),<------ attachment
   null,
   null
   null,
   _PS_MAIL_DIR_,
   false,
   (int)$order_id
);
```